# Spring Integration TcpInboundGateway:TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : Server Socket closed exception

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration TcpInboundGateway in my app that receives requests(packets) from remote clients over TCP channel.The configuration as follows:

```
@Bean 
    ByteArrayCrLfSerializer ser()
    {
        return new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
    }

    @Bean
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf(){
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(45456);

        connectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        connectionFactory.setSerializer(ser());
        connectionFactory.setDeserializer(ser());


        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    TcpInboundGateway tcpGate(){

        TcpInboundGateway gateway=new TcpInboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(cf());
        gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
        gateway.setRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel(){

        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

As per my knowledge it supports multithreading. But when lot of requests comes at same time apllication stop working with following error message.

```
2016-06-13 06:12:52.330  INFO 1431 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : Server Socket closed
```

Is there any any configuration missing to support multithreading to handle large number of requests concurrently.

Comment: That error message implies you have called `stop()` on the connection factory or the inbound gateway. AFAIK, that's the only way the server socket can go to that state. There's nothing special you have to do to handle multi-threading.

Comment: i am not calling stop() but whenever there is large number of requests to socket.Then above error message comes and then it will not accept new requests.

Comment: If you are opening sockets at a fast rate, you might want to increase the backlog. It shouldn't cause the server socket to close though, just cause some refused connections.

Comment: I mean I've never seen a server socket spontaneously close like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough StackTrace, though... Although that may be as a reason of that `gateway.setRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT);` when your downstream process can't catch up all the incoming messages. Consider to make it infinite.

Or take a look to your services and try to figure out why they don't work in multithreading properly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Non-Blocking I/O by means of TcpNioServerConnectionFactory instead of TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.
Some docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#note-nio